# Pasted text in Word goes off the page edge

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-powerpoint

I converted a PowerPoint file into Word document using an online converter, and now I'm copying the text from the converted Word document into a new Word document.

However, the pasted text is running off the edge of the page.

I suspect this is because the PPT slideshow was in landscape layout and the converted Word document is too.

I tried inserting a text box and pasting into it, but I get the same result.

I tried to change the layout of the converted document to portrait, but that didn't work either.

What else can I try?

Comment: Why did you need a converter at all? Why not just copied the text? Is the text fine in the converted file correct,  but not in the new one? What's the difference between formatting of the two files? Please post some screenshots to help us understand your problem.  "Its very urgent" - this is not the right place for urgent questions,  this a community helping each others without any expectations when you get answer.

Comment: Did you tried pasting without formating?

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**

Open the original PowerPoint file, or the converted document and copy the text you need.

**Step 2**

Open your destination Word document, choose the location you wish to paste the text, and right-click.

**Step 3**

Observe the right-click menu:

[image: Word 2016 right-click menu]

Under **Paste Options** click the third option. This is "Paste text only" and will remove most associated formatting.

[image: Used Paste Text Only option]

**Step 4**

Benefit!

**NOTES:**

There is a possibility this will not work. If, for instance, the original PowerPoint file and the converted Word document contain images, not text. In this case, you may try RK's OCR option.

This "Paste Text Only" feature has been in MS Word since Office 2010, I believe. If you have an earlier version or do not see this button, please use RK's **Method 1**.

Answer (score 0):

As per your given information that you have a `.pptx` [*PowerPoint*] file which you have converted into a *Word file* (lets call it as '*Myfile.docx*') using some online conversion tool and you want to copy and paste the content (text) to another New *Word File*.
I think you can do so follow the steps below (I am supposing that the converted 'Myfile.docx' file have correct formatting).

**Method I:**
In this method we will use the converted file from PowerPoint to Word that is 'Myfile.docx'.

**Step 1:** Open the '*Myfile.docx*' file.
**Step 2:** Now Open *Notepad*.
**Step 3:** *Copy* the texts from *Word File* '*Myfile.docx*' and *paste* it to *Notepad*.
**Step 4:** Now Open a *New Word File* (lets call it as '*NewMyfile.docx*').
**Step 5:** Now *copy* the content of *Notepad* and *paste* it to '*NewMyfile.docx*'.
**Step 6:** Repeat *Step 3* and *Step 5*.

**Method II:**

**Step 1:** Open your *PowerPoint* File `.pptx`.
**Step 2:** Now save it as `.jpg` (image file) using "**Save As**" Option (while exporting choose '*All Slides*' Option).
**Step 3:** Now Browse a '*Online OCR*' site and apply OCR on your Image files and generate output in `.txt` (text file) format.
**Step 4:** Now *copy* the content of text file (`.txt`) to a new *Word Document*.
**Step 5:** Save your new Word File with all the contents in it.

**Done!**

Comment: Method 1 is OK, but Method 2? No, don't, is the path to pain and suffering and failure. Also, Word has a built-in paste-method selector in the right-click menu. One of these options is essentially a one-step version of your Method 1.